# Set the child's width relative to parent with presence of margin

Tags: html, css

I want to set the width of a `header` realtive to `conatiner` width with taking into account `header`'s margin

```css
div.container {
  width:  100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
    
header{
  width: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid green; 
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
</div>
```

but `header` element gets out from the border of container on a few pixels on the right side. 
Also tried to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `header`'s style, nothing happened. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `width: calc(100% - 22px);`for `header`. That's 100% minus twice the border (2 * 1px) minus twice the margin (2*10px), adding up to 22px.

```css
div.container {
  width:  100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
    
header{
  width: calc(100% - 22px); 
  border: 1px solid green; 
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
</div>
```

Comment: because none of the available settings for box-sizing (border-box, content-box, padding-box) takes margins into account - margins are *outside* the element.

Comment: is there more elegant way to calculate the width? What if I want to change margin later or even add padding? I need to modify `calc` function also

Comment: then you'd need to use javascript/jQuery to get those values dynamically

Comment: or you use LESS or SASS - then you can define that margin value as a variable and use it that in your LESS/SASS. That way you'd have to make only one change, but it's less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest instead of using margins on child div - use `padding:10px` on parent div. I've updated your code snippet.

```css
div.container {
  width:  100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
}
    
header{
  width: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid green; 
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
</div>
```